# Lag between switching tab fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-tabs

I am having a problem that whenever I switch between different tabs, the process lags for a second or two. How can I remove this lag? There is no such thing in oncreate function of the fragments. I am posting the code here.

This is the code for the activity that is calling the fragment Dashboardnew :

```
private void setupDrawerContent(final NavigationView navigationView) {
    //revision: this don't works, use setOnChildClickListener() and setOnGroupClickListener() above instead
    expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(i==0) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"View Tasks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (filterApplied) {
                    persistentbottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    persistentbottomSheet.bringToFront();
                    fab.bringToFront();
                }
                fragment = new DashboardNew();
                if (fragment != null) {
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dashboard_frame, fragment).commit();
                    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
              /* new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            manager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.dashboard_frame, fragment)
                                    .commit();

                        }
                    }
                }, 300);*/
                //drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }

            if(i==1) {

            }

            if(i==2) {
                prefs.edit().remove("firstTime").apply();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Login.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long l) {
            if (groupPosition == 1 && childPosition == 0) {
                fabvisibility = false;
                //so this code only executes if the 2nd child in the 2nd group is clicked
                fragment=new AddUser();
                if (fragment != null) {
                    manager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.dashboard_frame, fragment,"AddUser")
                            //.add(fragment,"AddUser")
                           // .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                            .commit();
                }
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }

            if (groupPosition == 1 && childPosition == 1) {
                //so this code only executes if the 2nd child in the 2nd group is clicked
                fabvisibility = false;
                fragment=new ViewUsers();
                if (fragment != null) {
                    manager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.dashboard_frame, fragment)
                            .commit();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The code for Dashboardnew fragment is :

```
    initialize(rootview);
    clicklisteners();
    createViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    createTabIcons();

    return rootview;
}

 private  void clicklisteners()
 {
     usualTasks.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("The Checklist");
}
 @Override
 public  void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.toggleButton: {

             if(usualTasks.isChecked()) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toggle button is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 showRoleDialog();
                 FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 trans.replace(R.id.base_pending, new UsualTasks());

                 WelcomeActivity.persistentbottomSheet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 //WelcomeActivity.fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                 trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                 trans.commit();
             }
             else {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toggle button is Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 trans.replace(R.id.usual_pending, new PendingTasks());
                 trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                 if (WelcomeActivity.filterApplied == true) {
                     WelcomeActivity.persistentbottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     WelcomeActivity.persistentbottomSheet.bringToFront();
                     WelcomeActivity.fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 }
                 if(UsualTasks.shown) {
                     UsualTasks.mSnackBar.dismiss();
                 }

                 trans.commit();
             }
         }
     }
 }

public void populateList(HashMap<Integer, String> myMap, List myList){
    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> setMap = myMap.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,  String>> iteratorMap = setMap.iterator();
    int item=0;
    while(iteratorMap.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>) iteratorMap.next();
        myList.add(entry.getValue());
        item++;
    }
}

private  void showRoleDialog() {
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.usualtask_dialog);
     rolelist = new ArrayList<Map<Integer,String>>();
     roles= new HashMap<Integer, String>();

     roles.put(1, "Senior Manager");
     roles.put(2, "Admin");
     roles.put(3, "HR");
     populateList(roles,rolelist);

     ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, rolelist)
     {
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
             // Get the current item from ListView
             View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
             TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
             tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#353b41"));
             return view;

         }
     };
     dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

     selectRole= (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectrole);
     submitRole= (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btsubmitrole);
     selectRole.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
     selectRole.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

     selectRole.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}
     });

    submitRole.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });

     dialog.show();
 }

private void createTabIcons() {
    RelativeLayout tabOne = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pending_tab, null);
    TextView textTab=(TextView)tabOne.findViewById(R.id.tab);
    ImageView imageTab=(ImageView) tabOne.findViewById(R.id.notifyimage);

    //TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound("999",Color.RED); // radius in px
    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRoundRect("999",Color.RED,18); // radius in px
    imageTab.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    textTab.setText("Pending");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabOne);

    RelativeLayout tabTwo = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.completed_tab, null);
    TextView textTab1=(TextView)tabTwo.findViewById(R.id.pending_tab);
    textTab1.setText("Completed");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabTwo);
}

private void initialize(View rootview) {
    toolbar = (Toolbar)rootview.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    usualTasks=(ToggleButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
}

private void createViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new DashboardNew.ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new CompletedTasks(), "Completed");
        adapter.addFrag(new PendingTasks(), "Pending");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return new CompletedTasks();
        else
            return new PendingTasks();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the code for Completed tasks:

```
    completedTaskList = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.completedlist);
    BaseMenuActivity.filterState=false;

    if(UsualTasks.shown) {
        UsualTasks.mSnackBar.dismiss();
    }

    generateListdata();

    return rootview;
}

private void generateListdata() {
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("Call the Owner","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.access_dashboard));
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("Check the safety of patients","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.safety_dashboard));
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("Admin needs to do specific task","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.admin_dashboard));
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("Get the specific work done","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.access_dashboard));
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("Need to hire more resources","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.hr_dashboard));
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("How are patients behaving?","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.patient_experience_dashboard));
    completedTasks.add(new completedTasks("Need to adjust the audit report","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.completed_tick,R.drawable.finance_dashboard));

    //getListView().setDividerHeight(10);
    ArrayAdapter<com.example.attech.checklist_attech.Model.completedTasks> adapter = new CompletedTaskAdapter(getContext(), 0,completedTasks);
    completedTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);

    completedTaskList.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {}

            if (position == 1) {}

            if (position == 2) {
                //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ViewUser.class);
                //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}


}
```

This is the code for pendingtasks:

```
initialize(rootview);
        generateListdataAssigned();
        generateListdata();
        generateselectall();
        clickListeners();

        return rootview;
    }

    private void clickListeners() {
        assignTask.setOnClickListener(this);
        assignTaskbottom.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void populateList(HashMap<Integer, String> myMap, List myList){
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> setMap = myMap.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,  String>> iteratorMap = setMap.iterator();
        int item=0;
        while(iteratorMap.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>) iteratorMap.next();
            myList.add(entry.getValue());
            item++;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.assignTaskPending: {
                selected = !selected;

                if (selected) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Assigned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    assignTask.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+WelcomeActivity.filterApplied,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pendingTaskListAssigned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    WelcomeActivity.persistentbottomSheet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    selectAllListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    assignTaskbottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pendingTaskList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+WelcomeActivity.filterApplied,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pendingTaskListAssigned.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    assignTaskbottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    selectAllListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    assignTask.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_grey);
                    pendingTaskList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (WelcomeActivity.filterApplied) {
                        WelcomeActivity.persistentbottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        WelcomeActivity.persistentbottomSheet.bringToFront();
                        WelcomeActivity.fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case R.id.btassignTask: {
                showAssignTaskDialog();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private  void initialize(View rootview) {
        pendingTaskList = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.pendinglist);
        pendingTaskListAssigned = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.pendinglistassigned);
        assignTask = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.assignTaskPending);
        assignTaskbottom = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.btassignTask);
        selectAllListView= (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.selectalllist);
    }

    private void generateListdataAssigned() {
        pendingTasksAssigned.add(new pendingTasks("System Tasks","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.safety_dashboard));
        pendingTasksAssigned.add(new pendingTasks("Call answer speed","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.access_dashboard));
        pendingTasksAssigned.add(new pendingTasks("Appointment reasons","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.access_dashboard));
        pendingTasksAssigned.add(new pendingTasks("Admin needs to do specific task","Wembley GP","Daily",R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.hr_dashboard));

        ArrayAdapter<pendingTasks> adapter = new PendingAssignedAdapter(getContext(), 0, pendingTasksAssigned);
        pendingTaskListAssigned.setAdapter(adapter);
        pendingTaskListAssigned.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkboxassigned);
                checkBox.performClick();

                if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                    countChecks = countChecks + 1;
                }
                else{
                    countChecks = countChecks - 1;
                }

                if(check == true){
                    selectAllListView.setItemChecked(0, false);
                    check = !check;
                }

                if(countChecks == pendingTaskListAssigned.getCount()){
                    selectAllListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
                    check = ! check;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //populating the arraylist, creating an adapter and setting it to a list view
    private void generateListdata() {
        pendingTasks.add(new pendingTasks("System Tasks", "Wembley GP", "Daily", R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.safety_dashboard));
        pendingTasks.add(new pendingTasks("Call answer speed", "Wembley GP", "Daily",  R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.access_dashboard));
        pendingTasks.add(new pendingTasks("Appointment reasons", "Wembley GP", "Daily", R.drawable.pending_clock_icon, R.drawable.access_dashboard));

        ArrayAdapter<pendingTasks> adapter = new PendingTaskAdapter(getContext(), 0, pendingTasks);
        pendingTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);
        pendingTaskList.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                showInputDialog();

                if (position == 0) {}

                if (position == 1) {
                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddUser.class);
                    //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ViewUser.class);
                    //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private  void generateselectall() {
        selectallList= new ArrayList<Map<Integer,String>>();
        selectall= new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        selectall.put(1, "Select All");
        populateList(selectall,selectallList);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, selectallList)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                // Get the current item from ListView
                View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setTextSize(13);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
                // Set the height of the Item View
                params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                view.setPadding(37,0,10,10);
                return view;
            }
        };



        selectAllListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        selectAllListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        selectAllListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int firstListItem = pendingTaskListAssigned.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int lastVisibleItem = pendingTaskListAssigned.getFirstVisiblePosition() + pendingTaskListAssigned.getChildCount() - 1;
                check = ! check;

                for(int i=0; i < pendingTaskListAssigned.getCount(); i++){
                    if(i>lastVisibleItem || i<firstListItem){
                        View item = (View) pendingTaskListAssigned.getAdapter().getView(i, null, pendingTaskListAssigned);
                        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)item.findViewById(R.id.checkboxassigned);
                        checkbox.setChecked(check);
                    }
                    else{
                        ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup)pendingTaskListAssigned.getChildAt(i - firstListItem);
                        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)item.findViewById(R.id.checkboxassigned);
                        checkbox.setChecked(check);
                    }
                }

                if(check == true){
                    countChecks = pendingTaskListAssigned.getCount();
                }
                else{
                    countChecks = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void showInputDialog() {
        final  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.task_dialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        tbutton = (ToggleButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toollamp= (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.lamptool);
        tooli= (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.itool);
        tooldetails= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tooldetail);
        submit=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btsubmit);

        toollamp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tooldetails.setText("Target for staff 2 rings and answer.Check daily for 2x 5 mins");
            }
        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        tooli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tooldetails.setText("Check daily for 2x 5 mins");
            }
        });

        tbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(tbutton.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toggle button is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toggle button is Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void showAssignTaskDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.assign_task_dialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        Close= (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        myself=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btmyself);
        others=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btothers);

        Close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        myself.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Myself", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        others.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Others", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent= new Intent(getContext(), AssignTasks.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code first =)

Comment: fragment have onResume.. how many tabs do you have? what data do you load? how many hierarchy in your xml?

Comment: The code is here now :D I am new to stackoverflow too... so i stackoverflow-ed how to add code to the question too xD

Comment: @Pousti show CompletedTasks fragment and PendingTasks fragment

Comment: @DEADMC i just updated it. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who have this problem , please use cardviews and recyclerviews. The data was too much for list view. Used cardviews and recyclerviews instead , and the lag was gone.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I cant get why you create fragments twice

You actually create fragments here

```
private void createViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new DashboardNew.ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new CompletedTasks(), "Completed");
        adapter.addFrag(new PendingTasks(), "Pending");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And then you create them here. Again

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return new CompletedTasks();
    else
        return new PendingTasks();
}
```

I guess right way is removing these lines

```
adapter.addFrag(new CompletedTasks(), "Completed");
adapter.addFrag(new PendingTasks(), "Pending");
```

In other case you will have big problems with screen rotation.

You can set offscreen limit (by default its 1 only), so fragments will be created only one time and will not be removed

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Also I refuse to understand what these lines mean

```
   completedTasks.add(new completedTasks(...);
```

Is it CompletedTasks fragment? What do you add and how?

Comment: I cant remove these lines of code because if i do the application crashes.. plus the lines completedtasks.add are to add new element in the list of completed tasks.

Comment: this is the code of completedTasks.   
`code` public completedTasks(String Taskname, String Practicename, String timeline, int taskimage,int categoryimage){
        this.Practicename = Practicename;
        this.Taskname = Taskname;
        this.timeline = timeline;
        this.taskimage=taskimage;
        this.categoryimage=categoryimage;
        this.practiceimage=practiceimage;
        this.timeimage=timeimage;
    }

Answer (score 1):

> There is no such thing in onCreate() function of the fragments.

But it is still lagging, right? I think the problem is with your layout which is too heavy because the only work you are doing in onCreateView() is setting your layout.

Please check if your images are of very high pixel density. This is a most common mistake. Android System takes time to convert those high pixel images in layout to lower pixel density which is suitable for your device which takes time and causes lag.
Other reason could be bad layout hierarchy.

Comment: ìmages are of high resolution but in a good app, you ought to use resources with good definition. What about layout can you please elaborate? help me in this problem. I am stuck on this for a day

Answer (score 0):

you should extends your container activity from **FragmentActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
}
```

> this is very fast switch between fragment.

is better using  tag in xml layout
and show , hide when click the tab or bottom tabs

//code example :

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
.show(fm.findFragmentById(fragment))
 .hide(fm.findFragmentById(activePage))
 .commit();
```